# apt get-update error on Ubuntu 14.04.02

Tags: 14.04, apt

I'm getting this error on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.02:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Impossibile risolvere "extras.ubuntu.com"
Err security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"
Err it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"
Err security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Impossibile risolvere "security.ubuntu.com"
Err it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
W: Impossibile recuperare it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease 
W: Impossibile recuperare it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease 
W: Impossibile recuperare it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease 
W: Impossibile recuperare security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease 
W: Impossibile recuperare extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease 
W: Impossibile recuperare it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"
W: Impossibile recuperare it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"
W: Impossibile recuperare it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"
W: Impossibile recuperare extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Impossibile risolvere "extras.ubuntu.com"
W: Impossibile recuperare security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Impossibile risolvere "security.ubuntu.com"
W: Impossibile scaricare alcuni file di indice: saranno ignorati o verranno usati quelli vecchi.
```

Comment: Looks like your DNS servers are down; are you able to connect to the internet? Could you add the output of `ping -c 4 google.com`?

Comment: Oops, yes, the problem is no internet connection..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your Internet connection, or at least your DNS servers are down (`Impossibile risolvere "it.archive.ubuntu.com"`). Please check that your Internet connection is working.